# Changing a users shell with a script?

Tags: linux, git, bash, shell

Is there a proper way to change a user's shell variable with a script depending on what shell they use? Such as

```
GITSHELL=/bin/bash
if [ GITSHELL = $SHELL ]
then 
chsh git -s /usr/bin/git-shell
else
chsh git -s /bin/bash
```

Obviously there is some problems with this. I'm not sure how to word this so i can 
A: Run it as root and still call the user git's shell instead of root's using su in the statement somewhere or 
B: Run it as git and su -c root to change git's shell after the initial if?

The goal is to have a script i can run to change the user git's shell to bash when i need that user to temporarily have to ability to create folders and run git init --bare. And then i would run the script again to change the shell back to git-bash for security reasons.
Is this possible or should i go about this a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the user make that decision, controlled via an environment variable. Just write your script like this:

```
: ${GITSHELL:=/usr/bin/git-shell}

git -s "$GITSHELL"
```

Now, your script will use `/usr/bin/git-shell` unless explicitly overriden:

```
$ ./script.sh                     # use /usr/bin/git-shell
$ GITSHELL=/bin/bash ./script.sh  # use /bin/bash
```